# Is $\sigma(X_1,Y_1)=\sigma(X_2,Y_2)$ iff $\operatorname{Lin}(X_1,Y_1)=\operatorname{Lin}(X_2,Y_2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ be random variables on a probability space such that

$$\{aX_1+bY_1 : a,b\in \mathbb R \}=\{cX_2+dY_2 : c,d\in \mathbb R \}$$

Are the sigma-algebras $\sigma(X_1,Y_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2,Y_2)$ the same ?

Intuitively, I feel it should be true, but I have no clue how to prove it. What about the other way around ? If $\sigma(X_1,Y_1)=\sigma(X_2,Y_2)$, does it mean

$$\{aX_1+bY_1 : a,b\in \mathbb R \}=\{cX_2+dY_2 : c,d\in \mathbb R \}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reversing the roles of $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$, it suffices to show one inclusion. Note that $X_1$ belongs to $\{aX_1+bY_1 : a,b\in \mathbb R \}$ hence there exists $c,d\in\mathbb R$ such that $X_1=cX_2+dX_2$ hence $\sigma(X_1)\subset \sigma(X_2,Y_2)$. Similarly, $\sigma(Y_1)\subset \sigma(X_2,Y_2)$ hence the $\pi$-system of sets of the form $A_1\cap B_1$, where $A_1\in \mathcal \sigma(X_1)$ and $B_1\in  \mathcal \sigma(Y_1)$, is contained in $\sigma(X_2,Y_2) $.

The converse is not true: if we take $Y_1=Y_2=0$, $X_1$ a non-negative random variable and $X_2=X_1^2$, then $\sigma(X_1,Y_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2,Y_2)$ are equal but we can choose $X_1$ such that $X_1=aX_1^2$ never hold almost surely.